# Android listview sorting using xml parsing

Tags: java, android, sorting, xml-parsing, hashmap

I am having a bit of trouble with android. I have a sorted listview of items retrieved from a database using xml parsing.

i have to **display the product on list view with sorted by price**

This is my xml feed:

```
<Feed>
<category>
<Product>
<Name>New Masters of Flash</Name>
<Price>79.99</Price>
</Product>
<Product>
<Name>Professional Java Server Programming</Name>
<Price>63.99</Price>
</Product>
<Product>
<Name>Designing Web Usability</Name>
<Price>80.00</Price>
</Product>
</category>
 </Feed>
```

This is my android code:

```
public class Catalogue extends Activity {

// static String URL = "https://dl.dropbox.com/u/48258247/catalogue.json";
static final String URL = "http://192.168.1.168/xcart432pro/internet.xml";

 static String KEY_CATEGORY = "Product";
 static final String KEY_TITLE = "Name";

static final String KEY_DESCRIPTION = "Description";
static final String KEY_COST = "Price"; 
static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "Image";

ListView list;
ListAdapter adapter;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_CATEGORY);

        // looping through all song nodes &lt;song&gt;
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            // adding each child node to HashMap key =&gt; value

            map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
           map.put(KEY_DESCRIPTION, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESCRIPTION));
            map.put(KEY_COST, parser.getValue(e, KEY_COST));
          map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THUMB_URL));

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            songsList.add(map);
        }

        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
        adapter=new ListAdapter(this, songsList);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
       // Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

        // KEY_CATEGORY=bundle.getString(KEY_SUBCATE); 


        // Click event for single list row
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                HashMap<String, String> map = songsList.get(position);
                Intent in = new Intent(
                        Catalogue.this,
                        com.ssmobileproductions.catalogue.SingleMenuItem.class);
                in.putExtra(KEY_TITLE, map.get(KEY_TITLE));
                in.putExtra(KEY_DESCRIPTION, map.get(KEY_DESCRIPTION));
                in.putExtra(KEY_THUMB_URL, map.get(KEY_THUMB_URL));
                in.putExtra(KEY_COST, map.get(KEY_COST));
                startActivity(in);

            }

        });
```

Here i have to **display the product on list view with sorted by price**.How can i do.please help me programmatically in android.

**Edit**:
I have added some code like below:

```
Button btninsert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sort);
   btninsert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Collections.sort(songsList, new PriceComparator());
    }
    }); 
          final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_CATEGORY);
```

create one class and wrote the code below:

```
public class PriceComparator implements Comparator<HashMap<String, String>> {
static final String KEY_COST = "Price"; 

public PriceComparator() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

}



public int compare(HashMap<String, String> map1, HashMap<String, String> map2) {
    return map1.get(KEY_COST).compareTo(map2.get(KEY_COST));
}
```

Now i have to run the app and click the button means nothing is happened????

But i have to display product list is sorted by price.

Comment: what is the question? `How do you get the actual database row id of the item based upon the listview price?` or `to display the product on list view` because it seems like you can do both fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to use a custom Comparator:

```
Comparator<HashMap<String, String>> comparator = new Comparator<HashMap<String, String>>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(HashMap<String, String> map1, HashMap<String, String> map2) {
        return map1.get(KEY_COST).compareTo(map2.get(KEY_COST));
    }
};
```

And then sort your list before creating your adapter with:

```
Collections.sort(songsList, comparator);
```

---

**Addition**
You need to do make a few small changes.

1. Make `songsList` a field variable, like `list` and `adapter`:

   ```
   ListView list;
   ListAdapter adapter;
   ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList; // Add me!
   ```
2. Update how you initialize `songsList`:

   ```
   songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(); // Shorten me!
   ```
3. Change your `onClick` method:

   ```
   public void onClick(View v) {
       Collections.sort(songsList, comparator);
       adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // Add me!
   }
   ```

Comment: here what is meant by map1 and map2

Comment: `map1` and `map2` are used by `sort()`. Collections sorts your List by comparing each HashMap one at a time. I updated my answer.

Comment: Hi this is my full source code:http://pastie.org/5482747              i have to click this button means nothing is happened here.please help me.what mistake is done here

Comment: i have added this above code on my code.now i have to run the app and click button means nothing is happened???

Comment: thanks its worked successfully.thanks for your quick replies.

Answer (score 1):

> display the product on list view with sorted by price

=> As you are having ArrayList>, you need to create custom Comparator to make comparison.

For example:

```
public class PriceComparator implements Comparator<HashMap<String, String>> {

    public PriceComparator() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    public int compare(HashMap<String, String> map1, HashMap<String, String> map2) {
        return map1.get(KEY_COST).compareTo(map2.get(KEY_COST));
    }
}
```

And to apply this custom comparator to your ArrayList>, do like:

```
Collections.sort(mylist, new PriceComparator());
```

Comment: I like your approach (since I used the same basic idea), but your variables don't match.

Comment: @Paresh Mayani please read my edited question and give me solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Use Hashtable and sort the keys like following:

Here hashTable will contain name and price, and keys will contain the price, so sorting keys and then addind the sorted elements in sortedItems Vector will return you the sorted elements.

```
Hashtable hash = new Hashtable();
Vector<String> sortedItems = new Vector<String>();
Enumeration enumeration = hash .keys();
        Vector keySet = new Vector();
        while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
            keySet.add(enumeration.nextElement());
        }

        Collections.sort(keySet);
        Iterator i = keySet.iterator();
        String str;
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            str = (String) i.next();
            sortedItems.addElement(hash .get(str));
            Log.e("", (str + ":" + hash .get(str)));
        }
```